# ggplot: Setting fill and color to the same factor variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, fill, aesthetics

I'm plotting some points on a map of the US like this:

```
gmed2 <- ggplot() 
gmed2 <- gmed2 + geom_map(data = us, map = us, aes(x = long, y = lat, 
  map_id = region), fill = "white", color = "black", alpha = 0.7) 
gmed2 <- gmed2 + geom_map(data = states_map, map = states_map, 
  aes(x = long, y = lat, map_id = region), fill = "white", color = "black")
gmed2 <- gmed2 + coord_map("perspective", 2.5, orientation = c(30, -100, 0))
gmed2 <- gmed2 + geom_point(data = meddat, aes(x = Long_Dec, y = Lat_Dec, 
  fill = Task), shape = 21, alpha = 0.5)
gmed2 <- gmed2 + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1", 
  name = "Principal Mission", 
  labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"))
gmed2 <- gmed2 + theme_classic()  
gmed2 <- gmed2 + theme(legend.box.spacing = unit(-55, "pt"), 
  legend.position = "right",
  axis.line = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank(),
  axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
  legend.title = element_text(face = "bold"), 
  axis.title.x = element_blank(),
  axis.title.y = element_blank())
gmed2 <- gmed2 + theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
    legend.title = element_text(size = 10), 
    legend.text = element_text(size = 9))
gmed2
```

This works great - I get the map (with states) and the points appear colored by the factor variable `Task`.

I decided to add another data set on top of this one; it is shorter, but it uses the same variable names. In this case, I wanted to add their positions as open squares colored using the same (Brewer Set1) color scale. I added the following lines to the code above:

```
gmed2 <- gmed2 + geom_point(data = govdat, aes(x = Long_Dec, y = Lat_Dec, 
  color = Task), shape = 0, size = 3, alpha = 0.8)
gmed2 <- gmed2 + scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1", guide = FALSE)
```

I set `guide = FALSE` since the color scale should be the same (color and fill in this case).

The plot generates, but the colors for the two sets of data do not match (i.e., what is a red circle in the initial plot should now have a red open square around it, but it doesn't). I understand that the second set of data is more limited, so the `Task` variable doesn't contain all of the possible values that are in the original set.

I tried setting `group = Task` in both `geom_` statements, but that didn't help. I also tried adding a more detailed `scale_color_brewer` statement that matched the `scale_fill_brewer` statement to no avail:

```
gmed2 <- gmed2 + scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1", 
  name = "Principal Mission", 
  labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"))
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Try `scale_fill_brewer(...., aesthetics = c("fill", "color"))` and drop `scale_color_brewer`. Using the `aesthetics=` the same scale is applied to both color and fill.

Comment: Awesome! If you submit this as an answer, I'll mark it solved.